# how create an html table with all values from a serialized array in option_value

Tags: options

i am very new to wordpress and i have dived in deep waters in other peoples code :(. so i have this data array as an option_value in wp_options table

```
a:2:{s:16:"block1_names_arr"; a:7:{i:0; s:6:"name1"; i:1; s:9:"name2"; i:2; s:8:"name3"; i:3; s:12:"name4"; i:4; s:11:"name5"; i:5; s:7:"name6"; i:6; s:7:"name7"; }s:16:"block2_names_arr"; a:7:{i:0; s:44:"surname1"; i:1; s:76:"surname2"; i:2; s:62:"surname3"; i:3; s:86:"surname4"; i:4; s:67:"surname5"; i:5; s:68:"surname6"; i:6; s:48:"surname7"; }}
```

i want to create a two column table in the front end showing names and surnames per line.
i made a function and i managed to display the first set of data(the names) but i can't find a way to display the second

```
function names_table(){

$options = get_option('all_names');
$block1_names_arr = $options['block1_names_arr'];
$block2_names_arr = $options['block2_names_arr'];

$html = '

        <table class="table_open uv-table-dailies responsive table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Pick</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';

                foreach($block1_names_arr as $bookie){
                    $html.='<tr class="tr_open_res">
                        <td>'. $bookie .'</td>
                        <td>CANT DISPLAY THE SURNAMES HERE</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                $html.='
            </tbody>
            </table>';
return $html;}
```

i am not even sure if this is the correct way to do such a thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how you stored your data. Just answering from assumption:

```
<?php
$options = get_option('all_names');
?>

<table>
   <tbody>
      <?php
      $_counter = 0;
      foreach( $options as $option ) : ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $option['block1_names_arr'][$_counter]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $option['block2_names_arr'][$_counter]; ?></td>
         </tr>
      <?php
      $_counter++;
      endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked! i had to add $block1_names_arr = $options['block1_names_arr']; and $block2_names_arr = $options['block2_names_arr']; and change the echo to $block1_names_arr[$_counter] or else i was getting just Undefined index for block1_names_arr and block2_names_arr in the cells instead of values.

Comment: so what is better. add a function in functions.php and call it from where i need the table or just use the code in place?

Comment: my bad.. It works but it only returns the first 2 values instead of 7.

Comment: can't help without the `$options = get_option('all_names'); var_dump($options);`